# Check duplicate apache Flink when job failed

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using Kafka, Flink. My message read by Flink from Kafka then executes some business logic to DB and sends it to Third API (Ex: Mail, GG Sheet), Each message required to send exactly one. Everything work wells, but in case of Job failed and restart (I'm using checkpoint), any message relay and resend to Third API. I can you Redis to check the message that has been sent. In this way, each message should be checked in Redis, and affect performance. I wondering a solution doesn't need to use Redis to check duplicate.

Comment: From flink documentation, https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/guarantees.html, to guarantee end-to-end exactly-once record delivery (in addition to exactly-once state semantics), the data sink needs to take part in the checkpointing mechanism. In your case, only at least once can be provided out-of-the-box. The issue is that in order to provide exactly-once guarantee, two-phase commit should be performed on sink side. In case of Third API, it's hard to guarantee the two-phase transactionality - the job can fail just after the data gets sent to Third API.

Comment: In a similar case, we tried to do the following: in sink after the message got sent to Third API, we also wrote the last sent message identifier to a storage (in your case, it could be message id and Redis). On startup, we load the most recent ids sent to Third API and in data stream add additional filter which filters out records before this id (we operated on kinesis shards and seq nums, in your case it could be kafka partition id and offset, just will need to publish it through out the pipeline)

Comment: Does that mean we still needed to depend on Redis to check duplicate? And I wonder expire time of message_id in Redis? If this time is short and the application cannot restart before this time then we lost message_id. If this time is long then Redis will a lof of the message and may lead to a lot of memory.